# combine two tables into one output SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, Sales and Expenses

for example

Sales:

```
sales_date       Amount
2012-11-01      12000.55
2012-11-03       2650.00
2012-11-03       2650.00
2012-11-03       2650.00
2012-11-07      12900.00
2012-11-07       2900.00
```

Expenses:

```
Expense Date     Amount
2012-11-03         40.00
2012-11-10        100.00
2012-11-10       1000.00
2012-11-11         10.00
2012-11-17        100.00
```

I need SQL query output as

```
Date              Sales        Expense
2012-11-01      12000.55
2012-11-03       7950.00          40.00
2012-11-07      15800.00
2012-11-10                      1100.00
2012-11-11                        10.00
2012-11-17                       100.00
```

Comment: What is the FK relationship between the tables? It might require a JOIN operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a FULL OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT COALESCE(E.Date, S.Date) AS Date,
       SUM(S.Amount) AS Sales,
       SUM(E.Amount) AS Expenses
  FROM Expenses AS E
  FULL OUTER JOIN Sales AS S
    ON E.Date = S.Date
 GROUP BY COALESCE(E.Date, S.Date);
```

That is Standard SQL; we now have to find out whether MySQL supports it.  Unfortunately, as the commenter notes, [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html) does not support FULL OUTER JOIN.

In that case, you have to simulate FULL OUTER JOIN with a UNION of a LEFT OUTER JOIN and a RIGHT OUTER JOIN:

```
SELECT E.Date AS Date, SUM(S.Amount) AS Sales, SUM(E.Amount) AS Expenses
  FROM Expenses AS E
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Sales AS S
    ON E.Date = S.Date
 GROUP BY E.Date
UNION
SELECT S.Date AS Date, SUM(S.Amount) AS Sales, SUM(E.Amount) AS Expenses
  FROM Expenses AS E
 RIGHT OUTER JOIN Sales AS S
    ON E.Date = S.Date
 GROUP BY S.Date;
```

Comment: but the problem is `MySQL` doesn't supports `FULL OUTER JOIN`

Comment: thanks very much, first query doesnt support in mysql, second one worked fine

Comment: I have a problem, when I run the query, on '2012-11-03' there should be 3 records of 2650.00 but i get only one record and when I sum up the amounts I get 7950.00 and Expense 120.00 (this should be 40.00)

Comment: Inserted the SUM and GROUP BY clauses — apologies for missing the necessity for them the first time around.

Answer (score 1):

A nested query with a `UNION ALL` will give you what you need; first get all sales rows and all expense row separately, then `GROUP` them into common rows per date;

```
SELECT date, FLOOR(SUM(s)) AS sales, FLOOR(SUM(e)) AS expense
FROM
(
  SELECT sales_date  AS date, amount AS s, 0 AS e FROM sales
  UNION ALL     
  SELECT expensedate AS date, 0 AS s, amount AS e FROM expense
) AS individual_rows
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date;
```

The `FLOOR`'s can be left out if you don't want rounding (your result seems to indicate that you do)

[SQLfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fcbdb/14).

Comment: thanks very much Mr. Genius, your query gave me the expecting results.

Answer (score 0):

You need a full outer join. If mysql doesn't support it, look [here](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/05/26/how-to-write-full-outer-join-in-mysql/) for a possible workaround